# EAP-SIM with JRadius

Tags: authentication, radius, radius-protocol

I am trying to implement a radius client which authenticates via EAP-SIM. The radius client is using the JRadius framework (a requirement of the guys I'm working with), however it seems that JRadius doesn't have an authenticator for EAP-SIM.

Does anybody have any advice on how I might implement it myself (anybody with knowledge of JRadius?) or are there any suggestions for alternative implementations?

Many thanks,
Ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRadius has an abstract class RadiusAuthenticator from which all its provided authentication classes inherit. This has an abstract subclass EAPAuthenticator which extends RadiusAuthenticator. This then has a number of concrete subclasses for the different authentication protocols under the EAP framework. You would need to implement a similar subclass of EAPAuthenticator specifically for SIM. All of these classes are in the net.jradius.client.auth package and I believe the source code can be checked out using svn from the JRadius site. With plenty of pre-existing imlpementations it should be straightforward to get started on a new EAP extension.

Hope that helps,

Kate.